# What is the best practice for getting a content-uri for a file in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fileprovider

I have already registered a FileProvider in my manifest via:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
          android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Now, I want to get an URI for that file to pass to another app to open the file. I tried:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
Java.IO.File document = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
Android.Net.Uri contentUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(
    _context, Android.Support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS, document);

viewIntent.SetDataAndType(contentUri, GetMimeType(document));
viewIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
viewIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
Intent chooser = Intent.CreateChooser(viewIntent,
    "Which program shall open the file?");
chooser.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
chooser.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

_context.StartActivity(chooser);
```

Unfortunately, it seems that I can't adress `Android.Support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS` this way. How do I get my URI as cleanly as possibvle?

Comment: You should mark an answer once your query is solved not leave it in opened state sir!

Comment: @G.hakim : The solution to the problem is to use `_context.PackageName + ".provider` and I can only accept the answer in three hours from now. By design StackExchange doesn't let me select it at this point in time. Likely, because there's a chance that someone will still provide a better solution and thus the resulting reference resource would be better.

Comment: Whatever suits you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_context.PackageName + ".provider"` does the job (`_context` is a `Android.Content.Context`):

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
Java.IO.File document = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
Android.Net.Uri contentUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(
    _context, Android.Support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS, document);

viewIntent.SetDataAndType(contentUri, GetMimeType(document));
viewIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
viewIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
Intent chooser = Intent.CreateChooser(viewIntent,
    "Which program shall open the file?");
chooser.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
chooser.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

_context.StartActivity(chooser);
```